# Book Identification - Post Apocalyptic Novel - 70s/80s Main character Psychic w/Jet Black Skin

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic, mutant, psychic

I remember this as a paperback novel.  Main character had jet black skin and a psychic "danger" sense.  It was a post nuclear world. 70s or 80s book (I think). Main character was adult human male. I think he was not actually black by descent, but because he was some sort of mutant.  I remember him fighting gangs, sort of a Mad Max knock off.

Comment: Can you recall any other details? Also, was the character just a human with really dark skin, or not?

Answer (score 3):

Any chance that you're thinking of [***Telempath***](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?4806), by **Spider Robinson**? Here is a cover scan. (I found there are several to choose from -- several editions over the last 40 years, I guess.)

[image]

Here are some items that make me think it might match your description, allowing for some margin of error.

1. The novel-length version was published in paperback in **1976**. (It was an extended version of "By Any Other Name," which had previously won a Hugo for Best Novella.)
2. The main character (and narrator) is Isham Stone, a young man of African-American heritage. I can't remember if we were told that his skin was "jet black," though.
3. He did live in a postapocalyptic world, where the human population was only a fraction of what it used to be -- but nuclear war was not to blame.
4. Instead, due to a "mad scientist" doing something reckless (on purpose!), everyone had suddenly developed an *incredibly enhanced* sense of smell, and the massive sensory overload had caused a large portion of the human race to go crazy and die soon after being exposed to the catalyst that was spreading through the atmosphere. (In some cases, people died because *others* went berserk and killed them.)
5. The protagonist grew up well-adapted to this new set of circumstances, but the result was that instead of having a "psychic sense" per se, he routinely learned all sorts of interesting things (including other people's moods) from his nose; things which you and I either would never detect, or would only detect after we got very close to the source of a particular scent; whereas Isham Stone might smell it from hundreds of meters away. (I forget the exact range and limitations of his sense of smell; it's been a heck of a long time since I read this material.)

Comment: Stone's skin is never described as *jet black*. In fact I couldn't find the phrase *jet black* anywhere in the book.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a series of novels called Traveler by DB Drumm (pseudonym of John Shirley).
The book in particular you are thinking of could be [To Kill a Shadow](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2151699.To_Kill_a_Shadow) which is the 4th book in the series.
The main character in these books is a Mad Max type man named Traveler that has a kind of extra-sensory ability thanks to being exposed to neuro-toxins before the apocalypse.
The main antagonist in book 4 is a mutant biker with pitch black skin.